# Why ELF executables have a fixed load address?

Tags: compilation, linker, elf

ELF executables have a fixed load address (0x804800 on 32-bit x86 Linux binaries, and 0x40000 on 64-bit x86_64 binaries).

I read the SO answers (e.g., [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2187484/why-is-the-elf-execution-entry-point-virtual-address-of-the-form-0x80xxxxx-and-n)) about the historical reasons for those specific addresses. What I still don't understand is why to use a fixed load address and not a randomized one (given some range to be randomized within)?

Comment: I don't know ELF that well, but usually it is to have at least a chance of loading without relocation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> why to use a fixed load address and not a randomized one

1. Traditionally that's how executables worked. If you want a randomized load address, build a `PIE` binary (which is really a special case of shared library that has startup code in it) with `-fPIE` and link with `-pie` flags.
2. Building with `-fPIE` introduces runtime overhead, in some cases as bad as 10% performance degradation, which may not be tolerable if you have a large cluster or you need every last bit of performance.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on runtime overhead or give some links?

Comment: [c - How much overhead can the -fPIC flag add? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15861759/how-much-overhead-can-the-fpic-flag-add)

Answer (score 5):

not sure if I understood your question correct, but saying I did, that's sort-off a "legacy" / historical issue, ELF is the file format used by UNIX derived operating systems, both POSIX (IOS) and Unix-like (Linux).

and the elf format simply states that there must be some resolved and absolute virtual address that the code is loaded into and begins running from... 
and simply that's how the file format is, and during to historical reasons that cant be changed... you couldn't just "throw" the executable in any memory address and have it run successfully, back in the 90's when the ELF format was introduced problems such as calling functions with virtual tables we're raised and it was decided that the elf format would have absolute addresses within it.

Also think about it, take a look at the elf format -https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format
how would you design an OS executable-loader that would be able to handle an executable load it to ANY desired virtual address and have the code run successfully without actually having to change the binary itself... if you would like to do something like that you'd either need to vastly change the output compilers generate or the format itself, which again isn't possible

As time passed the requirement of position independent executing (PIE/PIC) has raised and shared objects we're introduced in order to allow that and ASLR
(Address Space Layout Randomization) - which means that the code could be thrown in any memory address and still be able to execute, that is simply implemented by making sure that all calls within the code itself are relative to the current address of the executed instruction, AND that when the shared object is loaded the OS loader would have to change some data within the binary given that the data changed is not executable instructions (R E) but actual data (RW, e.g .data segment), which also is implemented by calling functions from some "Jump tables" ( which would be changed at load time ) for example PLT / GOT.... those shared objects allow absolute randomization of the addresses the code is loaded to and if you want to execute some more "secure" code you'd have to compile it as a shared object and and dynamically link it and load time or run time..

( hope I've cleared some things out :) )