# Linking a static library into a shared library without -fPIC

Tags: c++, linker, g++, libtool

I want to combine object files and a static library into a shared library but the static library shall not be exposed, it is only referred in the object files that go into the shared library. I think that in this case, I do not need to compile the static library with `-fPIC` but I do not know how to tell the linker that the fact that I will not use the symbols from the static library. As an illustration of my problem, take the following files:

File `foo.cpp`:

```
#include "static.h"
using namespace std;

string version_info()
{
    return static_version_info();
}
```

File `static.cpp`:

```
#include"static.h"
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
string static_version_info()
{
    std::vector<int> ivec;
    return to_string(ivec.size());
}
```

File `static.h`:

```
#ifndef STATIC_H
#define STATIC_H
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
std::string static_version_info();
#endif
```

Then do

```
$ g++ -c foo.cpp -o foo.o -fPIC
$ g++ -c static.cpp -o static.o
$ gcc-ar rcs static.a static.o
$ g++ -shared foo.o static.a
/usr/bin/ld: static.a(static.o): relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `_ZNSt6vectorIiSaIiEEC1Ev' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

**Question:**
How can I adjust the last command such I do not get an error? Is this possible?

*Note that I do not want to compile* `static.cpp` *with* `-fPIC` *and I do not need the symbols (here* `return_static_version_info()`*) in the shared library.*

Comment: I am not following your line of thought. If you `...will not use the symbols from the static library...` why do you need it linked in?

Comment: @SergeyA The static library is only used in an interface defined in the object files that are linked together with the static lib into the shared lib. I only access the static lib via this interface. And the question is if in this case I can avoid `-fPIC` for the static lib.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**You cannot** (or at least you should not) **link a static library into a shared library**.

Even if you happen to apparently succeed in linking a non-PIC static library `libX.a` into a shared library `libY.so`, the resulting thing won't have position-independent code (so would have a lot of "useless" or "annoying" relocations).

A shared library needs to contain only position-independent code (in practice); but a static library does not contain PIC.

> I do not want to compile static.cpp with -fPIC

But you really should.

Read Drepper's [*How to Write Shared Libraries*](https://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf) for details.

BTW, some Linux distributions (e.g. Debian) provide a `libc6-pic` package giving files such as `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc_pic.a` which are a static library of position-independent code. This might be used to extend your system's `libc.so.6` with e.g. your own function (or your own `malloc`, etc...).

In practice, you'll better recompile your static library code with `-fPIC`; BTW the x86-64 ISA was designed to facilitate PIC.

At last, if you care about optimizations, there are [many](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html) of them. Did you consider compiling and *linking* with `gcc -O3 -fPIC -flto` ? In some cases, you might consider `-ffast-math` (which enables optimizations against the C standard), or replacing `-O3` with `-Ofast`.

And you surely should use a recent GCC or Clang compiler (or a recent proprietary `icc`). [This old](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15861759/841108) question (mentioned in your comments) is about 4.7. Current GCC in fall 2018 is [GCC 8](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-8/), and [GCC 9](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-9/changes.html) is worked upon (so should appear in spring 2019). Current Clang is [Clang 7](http://releases.llvm.org/download.html). 
Compilers are continuously making progress on optimizations.

You might want to download the *source* tarball of the latest release of GCC or of Clang and build that on your computer. This is a good way to have a recent version of these compilers, since distribution makers often prefer an older variant of them (which is compatible even with non-standard compliant code).

Comment: Of course I can do with `fPIC` but I did not want to slow down my high-performance code from the static library. I thought it is OK to avoid `-fPIC` if I do not need the position independent code from outside (when using the shared library), only via an interface that is defined in the object files which are compiled with `-fPIC`. So this is not true and I still need it even for the static library whose functions will not be called from the user of the shared lib directly?

Comment: Are you sure that `-fPIC` slows down your code on `x86-64` ? Did you benchmark? What is the measured slowdown? The x86-64 ISA was designed to facilitate PIC

Comment: No, but I read about `-fPIC` that some optimizations are disabled. Yes, I know that one should not try to optimize without benchmarking...

Comment: Where did you read that? For what ISA? I tend to believe that your source is wrong.

Comment: The second answer of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15861759/how-much-overhead-can-the-fpic-flag-add