# Statically linking the dependencies of a shared object in linux

Tags: gcc, shared-libraries, static-libraries, static-linking, dynamic-linking

I'm trying to create a share object which has its own dependencies statically linked.

Here is an example:

```
/* File: add.c */
#include <stdio.h>

int add(int a, int b) {
  printf("Adding: %d %d\n", a, b);
  return a + b;
}
```

When I try to compile I get the following error:

```
$ gcc -g -shared -fPIC -o libadd.so add.c -Wl,-Bstatic -lc -Wl,-Bdynamic
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.a(malloc.o): relocation R_X86_64_TPOFF32 against `tcache' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.a(libc_fatal.o): relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `_dl_pagesize' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Running on `Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS` with `gcc (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0` and `GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.30`.

My questions:

1. How can I make the above work?
2. Would it be an issue if 2 `libc`s run simultaneously (one statically linked in my shared object and one from a hypothetical executable that will link against my shared object and libc)?

---

I also found this article [here](https://sunglint.wordpress.com/2012/09/05/static-linking-for-cxx-shared-objects/) highlighting a similar issue but without a solution.

Comment: You can link the static version of glibc to static executables only. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53086636/linking-a-static-library-into-a-shared-library-without-fpic). Also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57476533/why-is-statically-linking-glibc-discouraged). Whatever your problem is, static linking is probably not a solution.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I make the above work?

Normal build of `libc.a` does not have `-fPIC`. On `i386`, you can actually link non-PIC object files into a `.so`, but the result would be an `.so` which requires text relocations (`.text` of such `.so` can't be shared between processes).

But on `x86_64` you can't (relocations only have 4 bytes in the medium memory model, and you would need to relocate `.text` by more than +/-2GiB).

So to make this work, you must rebuild `libc.a` with `-fPIC`.

> Would it be an issue if 2 libcs run simultaneously (one statically linked in my shared object and one from a hypothetical executable that will link against my shared object and libc)?

Most things will work, but TLS may cause complications.

Comment: Thanks! Could you please elaborate a little bit further on what issue I might have with the TLS? Also, is there an easy way for to install `libc` with `-fPIC`? Is there a ready-made package I could install with `apt`?