# Error when linking LibRaw to shared object

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, linker-errors, pybind11, libraw

So, what i'm actually trying to is to build a shared object, that contains a python-includable-module, generated by [pybind11](https://github.com/pybind/pybind11). I got it as far as to have no syntax-errors in CLion, but when i try to compile it, it gives the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: //usr/local/lib/libraw.a(utils_libraw.o): relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `stderr@@GLIBC_2.2.5' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/cr3_to_python.dir/build.make:98: recipe for target 'cr3_to_python.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so' failed
make[3]: *** [cr3_to_python.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:77: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/cr3_to_python.dir/all' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/cr3_to_python.dir/all] Error 2
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:84: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/cr3_to_python.dir/rule' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cr3_to_python.dir/rule] Error 2
Makefile:118: recipe for target 'cr3_to_python' failed
make: *** [cr3_to_python] Error 2
```

When compiling with c++ i get something very similar:

```
$ c++ -O3 -Wall -shared -std=c++11 -fPIC -I/usr/include/python3.6m/ -I/usr/local/include/opencv4/ $(python3 -m pybind11 --includes) main.cpp -o cr3_to_python$(python3-config --extension-suffix) -lraw
/usr/bin/ld: //usr/local/lib/libraw.a(utils_libraw.o): relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `stderr@@GLIBC_2.2.5' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What annoys me the most is the actual error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: //usr/local/lib/libraw.a(utils_libraw.o): relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `stderr@@GLIBC_2.2.5' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
```

Because i didn't include anything related to stderr (from my point of view) in the code.

[main.cpp](https://pastebin.com/16jtgb3A)

[CMakeLists.txt](https://pastebin.com/iHsiuggE)

Comment: You need to recompile libraw with the pic flag, without it you can only include it in an executable not a shared library

Comment: @AlanBirtles if you look at the `c++` compile-command `-fPIC` was actually included! I also tried `set(CMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE ON)` in `CMakeLists.txt` but the outcome was the same

Comment: No, you're compiling your code with `fPIC`, you need to compile libraw with it too

Comment: Ah got it. Will try!

Comment: @AlanBirtles It worked wonderfully! Please write your comment as an answer, so that i can accept it as solved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When compiling a shared library on Linux and Macos (and probably other Unixy OSes) all code used in the library needs to be compiled in "position independent mode", this is because the compiler doesn't know where an executable will load your code so has to generate code which can be run from any address.

To generate PIC code you need to pass the `-fPIC` flag to GCC.

Note that all the code you want to compile into your shared library needs to be compiled in PIC mode, this includes code in static libraries. In your case you need to recompile `libraw.a` with `-fPIC` enabled.

Position independent code might be slightly slower but the difference is small so you can probably just compile all your code with `-fPIC` even if its being used directly in an executable. Apple recommends that all code including executables is position independent. See [How much overhead can the -fPIC flag add?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15861759/how-much-overhead-can-the-fpic-flag-add) for more details about performance.